# Flutter Image picker with max size of 5 mb

Tags: flutter, image, dart, flutter-dependencies

i am using image picker package in flutter , so i want to mention the max size of image selected should be 5 MB, in the package there is a parameter named imagequality which take 0-100, but  don't equivalent for 5 mb

```
 getImageFromGallery() async {
    try {
      var pickedfiles = await imagePicker.pickMultiImage(imageQuality: 5);

      if (pickedfiles.isNotEmpty) {

        



        for (int i = 0; i < pickedfiles.length; i++) {
          previewList.add(pickedfiles[i].path);
        }
        setState(() {});
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I hope this helps

```
 selectImagesFromImagePicker() async{
  // e.g 
  final knowSize = await defindSize(fileSelected, 2);
            if (double.parse(knowSize.toString()) > 5.0) {
              SomeSnackBar("File too large", "Limit is 5 mb below");
            } else {
              log("$knowSize mb", name: "FILE SIZE");
              filesChosen.add(File(x!));
            }
}  
  // Function to know the size of a certain file
  defindSize(String? path, int decimals) {
        final file = File(path!);
        int bytes = file.lengthSync();
        log("lengthSync $bytes", name: "FILE SIZE");
        double sizeMb = bytes / (1000 * 1000);
        // the return is mb default
        return sizeMb.toStringAsFixed(decimals);
        // below if you wanted to return suffix just uncomment them
        // const suffixes = ["b", "kb", "mb", "gb", "tb"];
        // var i = (m.log(bytes) / m.log(1024)).floor();
        // return ((bytes / m.pow(1024, i)).toStringAsFixed(decimals)) + suffixes[i];
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. I hope it is useful

```
chooseImage() async {
var maxFileSizeInBytes = 5 * 1048576; // 5MB (You'll probably want this outside of this function so you can reuse the value elsewhere)

XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
  source: ImageSource.gallery,
);
var imagePath = await pickedFile!.readAsBytes();

var fileSize = imagePath.length; // Get the file size in bytes
if (fileSize <= maxFileSizeInBytes) {
    // File is the right size, upload/use it
} else {
    // File is too large, ask user to upload a smaller file, or compress the file/image
}
```

}